# Why out of several str_replace() functions only the last one affects the string?

Tags: php

I have set up a very simple code snippet:

```
$string = 'Some random words. Some more random, very random words.';
$words = explode(" ", $string);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($words); $i++) {
    $word = $words[$i];
    $words[$i] = str_replace(".", "!", $word);
    $words[$i] = str_replace(",", "?", $word);
}

print_r($words);
```

The output is this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Some
    [1] => random
    [2] => words.
    [3] => Some
    [4] => more
    [5] => random?
    [6] => very
    [7] => random
    [8] => words.
)
```

Why only the second `str_replace()` function affect the string? If I remove the second `str_replace()` the first one works perfectly. It's not about usage of `str_replace()` but I believe me doing something very very simply wrong.

By the way - I am aware of `preg_replace()` and passing an array to `str_replace()` but would like to hear about this particular situation :).

**EDIT:**
Thank you all for blazing quick responses. I am in a shame for such an issue but it really didn't catch my eyes at first. Thanks everyone! I will accept the first correct answer by **Mike Brant**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because your second statement uses `$word` as the subject of replacement and not `$words[$i]` which was where you assigned the string after the first replacement.

You can fix by either working directly with `$words[$i]` the entire time, or working exclusively with your temp variable and then making assignment like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($words); $i++) {
    $word = $words[$i];
    $word = str_replace(".", "!", $word);
    $words[$i] = str_replace(",", "?", $word);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you were applying `str_replace` to the same string over and over again. You need to reassign the new string (with replaced characters) and perform another replace on the updated value

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($words); $i++) {
    $word = $words[$i];  //initial value
    $word = str_replace(".", "!", $word);  //change $word to modified text
    $word = str_replace(",", "?", $word);  //change $word to modified text
    $words[$i] = $word;
}
```

The `$word` value doesn't get changed by `str_replace`, so it remains the same. To change it, you need to assign the return value/result from `str_replace`

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($words); $i++) {        
    $words[$i] = str_replace(".", "!", $words[$i]);
    $words[$i] = str_replace(",", "?", $words[$i]);
}
```

Even shorter:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($words); $i++) {        
    $words[$i] = str_replace(array(".", ","), array("!", "?"), $words[$i]);        
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks. I have noticed that I am aware of the array argument, but still - great example :).

Comment: every new line or variable means more memory to the server..which lead to higher power consumption and less possible traffic..so save the planet ;)